# Welcome sound in Mathematica

Tags: sound

My first introduction with Mathematica was about eleven years ago. It was still version 4.2 which had a nice welcome sound whenever you opened a new notebook. However this welcome sound is absent in all newer versions. So, I was wondering if there is a way to add somehow this welcome sound (or any other music theme) in newer versions like 9 or 10. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I remember that.  Was it also in one of the demo notebooks?  If so, it should be on on the Library Archive somewhere.  But I cannot find it. http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/

Comment: I would also like to have the code to produce the original startup sound.

Comment: @Szabolcs unless anyone has a copy of version 4.2, it might be necessary to ask Arnoud for the sound file.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Didn't it come with the code to generate it?  I mean the function to write inside `Play`.  Maybe I remember wrong.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can't clearly recall what the sound was like, although I seem to remember it being something similar to the sound of a harp. You may be right, but I don't have any recollection of that, and I think it would be difficult to generate.

Comment: @Oleksandr If you have version 7 handy, the startup sound is `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "SystemResources", "Windows", "Startup.wav"}]`. Note this was only ever available on Windows.

Comment: @ilian thanks! That's a bit of unexpected nostalgia.

Comment: @ilian The same directory is also present in v9. If I copy-paste the .wav file into in will it work?

Comment: Probably not, since the option has been removed. But you could add to your `init.m` file something like `task := EmitSound[Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]]; RunScheduledTask[task, {0.25}]`

Comment: Funnily enough, one of the first things I did on fresh *Mathematica* installations back then was to turn the sound off. Not in the same league as that paperclip, but still…

Comment: @ilian Could you post a more detailed answer on how to edit the `init.m` file? BTW I have v9 and v10.

Comment: Vaggelis, just open the file in *Mathematica*, and paste @ilian's snippet in.

Comment: @J.M. First of all where this file is located? Second paste the rule anywhere I want inside?

Comment: @J.M. With a quick search in Mathematica's folder I found several `init.m` files in many sub-folders. Which of them should I edit?

Comment: Well, what OS are you on, first of all?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry I should nave mentioned it. I have v9 in Win XP SP3 and v10 in Win 7.

Comment: If memory serves, it's within the *hidden* AppData folder in your user directory. Also, see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html).

Comment: @J.M. Do you mean here: `C:\Documents and Settings\ZorinCorp\Application Data\Mathematica`? If so, there are several `init.m` files in the sub-folders.

Comment: I said your user directory; `C:\Users\loginname\AppData`, or `Application Data`, or whatever that folder's called these days.

Comment: @J.M. In C:\ there is no `Users\ folder...

Comment: Then in that case, it's that folder you mentioned earlier; look up the `init.m` within a "Kernel" folder.

Comment: @J.M. The `init.m` file in the "Kernel" folder contains only one line `(** User Mathematica initialization file **) which is commented.

Comment: As expected; make a new line, paste it in, and save.

Comment: @Now when I start the program a sound is played (not the original v4 welcome sound) but with a short time delay.  Can I remove this time delay?

Comment: @J.M. According to documentation in `RunScheduledTask[task, {0.25}]` the 0.25 defines the time delay. However if I set the value lower than 0.20 then when you open the program the sound is not played, while a second notebook opens.

Comment: Then, I'm not sure how to proceed further. I suggest that you edit your question with these additionals.

Answer (score 11):

There was a symbol called [`StartupSound`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/StartupSound.html). You could switch it on via the command:

> `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, StartupSound -> True]`

But according to [Wolfram Reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/StartupSound.html) it is no longer available.

Comment: It was removed in version 8.

Answer (score 6):

I've upload the sound from *Mathematica* [here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1ZIYnrIxtQk), you can now save it and have *Mathematica* play it in your `init.m`, hope this helps you.

Comment: This is a dead link.